# Drag and drop - Animation of shadow after DRAG_ENDED very slow

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I recently updated the API I was building against from v21 to 24 and noticed a change with the drag and drop events which isn't great.  On the older API when the drag event ends *without a successful drop on a target view* the shadow disappears and the `ACTION_DRAG_ENDED` action is triggered right away.  On the newer API first the shadow very slowly, painfully, animates back to its original position and only after that is done is the appropriate event triggered.

How can I either change the speed of that animation or remove it entirely?  I've had no real luck finding out in the docs.